# Subquery under Select - adding where clause to exclude data

Tags: sql, select, subquery

Hello I am pulling Volume information for our customer base and would like to write a subquery for the column [Volume2] under SELECT to pull Volume info if Fiscal Year = 2013.  As the query is currently written, all volume is currently included for Fiscal Years >= 2012 under WHERE clause but instead of changing it there, I want to specify it for the [Volume2] column under SELECT.  So [Volume1] column would include volume for Fiscal Years 2012 and 2013 and [Volume2] column would include only volume for 2013.

Any help appreciated!  Thanks!

```
SELECT 

sum([FactActualDetail].[Volume]) AS [Volume1],
sum([FactActualDetail].[Volume]) AS [Volume2],
sum([FactActualDetail].[AdjGrossMarginAmount]) AS [AdjGrossMarginAmount],
left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7) as [Acct #],
[DimDate].[Fiscal_Year] as [Fiscal_Year],
[DimCustomer].[TerrSalesManagerName] AS [TerrSalesManagerName],
[DimCustomer].[AccountRepsalesmanName] AS [AccountRepsalesmanName]

FROM [dbo].[FactActualDetail] [FactActualDetail] 

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] [DimCustomer] ON ([FactActualDetail].[CustomerSK] = [DimCustomer].[CustomerSK])
LEFT JOIN [Common].[DimDate] [DimDate] ON ([FactActualDetail].[DeliveryDateSK] = [DimDate].[DateSK])

WHERE [EQMultiplier] > 0 AND [Fiscal_Year] >= 2012 AND ([SuperChannelCode] = 04 OR [SuperChannelCode] = 06 OR [SuperChannelCode] = 07) AND (substring([SourceCustomerProductCode],8,3) = 102) 

GROUP BY left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7),[TerrSalesManagerName],[AccountRepsalesmanName],[Fiscal_Year]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Fiscal_Year = 2013 THEN FactActualDetail.Volume
         ELSE 0 END) AS Volume2
```

instead of just

```
SUM(FactActualDetail.Volume) AS volume2
```

in your query.